# How to insert the Map<String,List<other_table_type>> in orient db

Tags: orientdb

I have a table column in orient db, which has to be of form,
`column: [env1 : [R1,R2,R3],
         env2 : [R1,R2]]`

How can i achieve this?
I tried using LinkMap, linkset, linklist... But unable to achieve..

Comment: Hi, what version are you using? Thx

Comment: OrientDb v2.2.30

Answer (score 0):

EMDEDDEDMAP data type needs to be used for the column. Below is an example class with such a property:

```
CREATE CLASS Entity IF NOT EXISTS;

CREATE PROPERTY Entity.propertyAccessAssignments IF NOT EXISTS EMBEDDEDMAP EMBEDDEDSET STRING;
```

Query of the below form (SET will work with CREATE VERTX/EDGE also) can be used to insert data

```
UPDATE #216:0 SET propertyAccessAssignments={'a':['b']}
```

Where #216:0 is the rid of the record, standard where clause will also work